# Select query with multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need a query to select a common record from four table based on single condition from a table
I used a query which returns 240 records but the condition returns only 2 result sets.
Reference no from all the given tables are same.

```
 Select b.cdr_data
     ,a.cdr_data
     ,c.cdr_data
 from itaukei_data_store b
     ,itaukei_data_store_key a
     ,ITAUKEI_BANK_ACCOUNT c
     ,payment_data_store d
 where a.reference_no = b.reference_no 
     and a.reference_no=c.ITK_REFNO 
     and b.INDIVIDUAL_REFNO=d.INDIV_REF_NO 
     and d.remarks='Below 18 years';
```

But,

```
 select * from payment_data_store where remarks='Below 18 years';
```

Returns 2 records alone.

Comment: I haven't worked with oracle in a while but in these cases I always suggest to start with only 2 tables and work your way up to all four if the initial results are correct. Also, I am not sure what kind of JOIN is used when you just specify "from x,y,...". Try only 2 tables with a LEFT JOIN ... ON and see if it works. Then left join the other tables. This is how I build up my queries.

Comment: Your question is not much clear. Please show us your table structure, some data you have provided, and mention more clearly what you are actually expecting to get.

Comment: payment_data_store which has only 2 rows based on the condition. itaukei_data_store table has 120 rows based on the column INDIVIDUAL_REFNO in payment_data_store.

Comment: Yea but i need only two records from that 120 records. - Thevan

Comment: itaukei_data_store,itaukei_data_store_key,ITAUKEI_BANK_ACCOUNT and payment_data_store are based on reference num.Example the reference no from itaukei_data_store_key is equal to itaukei_data_store - Moon

Comment: Are the 240 results made of two 120 same records ? (2 distinct valvues)

Comment: First off, don't use the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause); among other things, it makes it too easy to drop conditions and get full Cartesian products (lotsa extra rows), and difficult to properly do `LEFT JOIN`s.  Use explicit joins properly (probably regular `INNER JOIN`s here).  From the sound of this (as A.B.Cade is pointing towards), your data isn't restricted enough - SQL is based on set math, and joined rows multiply together if there aren't sufficient criteria; essentially, you need to specify more conditions.

Answer (score 0):

### You Try like this

```
Select b.cdr_data,a.cdr_data,c.cdr_data,d.cdr_data
from itaukei_data_store b,itaukei_data_store_key a,
ITAUKEI_BANK_ACCOUNT   c,payment_data_store d
where a.reference_no = b.reference_no 
and b.reference_no=c.ITK_REFNO 
and b.INDIVIDUAL_REFNO=d.INDIV_REF_NO 
and d.remarks='Below 18 years';
```

Comment: Um, what?  This is just his original query (slightly reformatted) - this isn't answering his question at all...